# Why is react returning a TypeError: Cannot read properly 'join' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to display a list of books, and the name of the author(s) below.

In case there are multiple authors, I need to separate their names and I'm trying to use .join().

Below part of the code without .join():

```
<select
  onChange={(event) => this.props.changeShelf(
   this.props.book, event.target.value
  )}
  value={this.props.actualShelf}
>
  <option value='move' disabled>Move to...</option>
  <option value='currentlyReading'>Currently Reading</option>
  <option value='wantToRead'>Want to Read</option>
  <option value='read'>Read</option>
  <option value='none'>None</option>
</select>
</div>
  </div>
    <div className='book-title'>{this.props.book.title}</div>
    <div className='book-authors'>{this.props.book.authors}</div>                  
  </div>            
);
```

And next the code with .join():

```
<select
  onChange={(event) => this.props.changeShelf(
   this.props.book, event.target.value
  )}
  value={this.props.actualShelf}
>
  <option value='move' disabled>Move to...</option>
  <option value='currentlyReading'>Currently Reading</option>
  <option value='wantToRead'>Want to Read</option>
  <option value='read'>Read</option>
  <option value='none'>None</option>
</select>
</div>
  </div>
    <div className='book-title'>{this.props.book.title}</div>
    <div className='book-authors'>{this.props.book.authors.join(', ')}</div>                  
  </div>            
);
```

My issue is that if I don't use .join(), the page works well, but when I insert .join(), initially the page works, but when I go to the search page and try to look for a book, i get the following error: `"TypeError: Cannot read properly 'join' of undefined"`. What could I do to solve this issue?

Obs. 1: I didn't put the entire code, but if you need to see it from the beginning, please let me know and I will edit this post.

Obs. 2: This component isn't a Stateless Component but a Class Component, that's why if you need the entire component displayed here, please let me know.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox?

Comment: It is not the React that is throwing the error, it is JavaScript. It means `this.props.book.authors` is undefined so `join` of undefined throws error

Comment: @Gangadhar Jannu, how may I define it to not return me this error?

Comment: @jose-renato-m You can check whether the values is present and then perform join. You can achieve this using short circuting or conditional operator. Something like `this.props.book.authors && this.props.book.authors.join(' , ')`

Comment: mybe {this.props.book.authors} is undefined , and it is not a problem for the first code, but for the second it is because you are trying the access it like an array and that will throw an error

Comment: @SuleymanSah, sorry I'm a little new in the development world, I went to codesandbox and understand that it emulates for example a react framework. Do I need to put all my components there in order to reproduce what is happening?

Comment: Only the minimum code to run the application. But before this try Gangadhar Jannu 's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the JS native which throws the error, simply because there's an `undefined` object

```
{this.props.book.authors && this.props.book.authors.join(', ')}
```

Maybe you have a case where a book has no author?

Comment: Yes, I think maybe there is a case which a book has no author.

Comment: I would take this a bit further and say `{this.props.book.authors !== undefined && this.props.book.authors.join(', ')}` Or whatever the desired condition is.  Never rely on truthy/falsey in JS.  It is the source of too many hard to diagnose bugs.

Comment: @ruby_newbie Maybe it depends on the situation... do you see a case where this would bug?

Comment: Not as it exists in its current state.  That said as the system gets more complex not explicitly stating the condition can often result in bugs in my experience.